# Setting up Flow with Aimsun (examples/sugiyama.py)

Tags: python, flow-project

I can't seem to open `examples/aimsun/sugiyama.py`

I have installed **Aimsun Next 8.4.0** and I have already pasted its path in **AIMSUN_NEXT_PATH** variable in `flow/config.py`

Here's the error that I get;

```
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: 
'/home/daremapua/Aimsun_Next_8_4_0/Aimsun_Next'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered the same today. What worked for me was to use Aimsun 8.3.1 instead. I'll try to find out what's the issue with 8.4.